# Separate by Category Post Type

Tags: wp-query, database, table

Assuming i have this kind of data

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'Hotels','posts_per_page'=>-1));
```

but i want it to separate them by specific field (eg location) and to trigger this kind of output

```
<table>
<thead>
   <tr>
    <td>Japan</td>
    <td>China</td>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Hotel from China</td>
<td>Hotel from Japan</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hotel from China</td>
<td>Hotel from Japan</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You could loop over the results and check for the location meta field (assuming that you're saving the location by meta value). This way you can build tables head and content.

Comment: You can create two separate custom queries for each of the locations (as above said, might be a meta query - 'meta_key' => 'location', 'meta_value => 'Japan', an other one for China ), then loop through each of them in every table row.

Comment: Or do multiple separate queries based on the meta vale or term that distinguishes them. WP_Query doesnt have a way to ‘group’ results.

Answer (score 0):

## To get custom post type posts with specific category use custom taxonomy

Register the taxonomy name of the custom post type like location and then assign location to each post when you added new post.
Here is the example of the code

```
  add_action( 'init', 'hotels_my_taxonomy');
  function hotels_my_taxonomy(){
 // custom post type taxonomies
    $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Locations',
    'singular_name' => 'Location',
    'add_new' => 'Add Location',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Location',
    'all_items' => 'All Locations',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
    'new_item' => 'New Item',
    'view_item' => 'View Item',
    'update_item' => 'Update Location',
    'search_items' => 'Search Locations',
    'not_found' => 'No record found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No items found in trash',
    'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item',
    'menu_name' => 'Locations'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'hotels_location'),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        );
        register_taxonomy('hotels_location', array('hotels'), $args);
}
```

## then

## create taxonomy template page 'taxonomy-hotels_location.php'

and add the query to get the posts with this category name

```
   $cat_name = single_cat_title;
   $args = array( 'category_name' => $cat_name, 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'post_type' => 'hotels', 'paged' => $paged);
```

All the work is done.Good luck